# Inbuilt method for element wise comparison of 2 struct arrays in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, struct

I have a struct with the below structure,

```
//Number A struct that represents a new number to be addeded
type Number struct {
    Country   string `json:"country"`
    Number    string `json:"number"`
    CreatedAt string `json:"created_at"`
}
```

and I a getting a response array of this struct from the REST call and I need to do an element-wise comparison. Is there any inbuilt method to do the same or more efficient way to do it instead of using a for loop and iterating through the elements?

Comment: You may use the `==` operator to compare arrays of Number.   That said, you probably have a slice of number (`[]Number`) instead of an array.   If you do have a slice and upgrade to Go 1.18, use [slices.Equal](https://github.com/golang/exp/blob/d4f80a91470e45b31d944fe5f8383717bd92019f/slices/slices.go#L17).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any inbuilt method to do the same or more efficient way to do it instead of using a for loop and iterating through the elements?

Values of type `Number` can be compared with `==` directly.